# On equivalent definitions of minimal polynomial

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

Let $L|K$ be a field extension, let $\alpha$ be an element of $L$, algebraic over $K$. I want to show that the following definitions of minimal polynomial $f$ of $\alpha$ over $K$ are equivalent:

1) $f$ is monic, $f(\alpha)=0, \forall g\in F[X]\ (g(\alpha)=0 \Rightarrow f|g)$

2) $f$ is monic, $f(\alpha)=0, \forall g\in F[X] (g(\alpha)=0 \Rightarrow \deg(f)\leq\deg(g) )$

3) $f$ is monic, $f(\alpha)=0,  f$ is irreducible in $F[X]$.

I've been able to show 1) implies 2) and 2) implies 3), but it seems to me more difficult to show that 3) implies 1). How can be proven this implication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 3) implies 1), look at $h=gcd(f,g)$ it is a polynomial of $F[X]$ with $\alpha$ as a root, thus it is non constant. Since $h$ divides $f$ and  $f$ is irreducible (using 3), $h$ is a constant multiple of $f$.

As a consequence, $f$ divides $g$.